# Perl certificate authentication

Tags: perl, curl

I am trying to verify a cert using perl.  I can verify the cert and get a response with curl but how do I convert. the following to perl.

```
curl -i --cert /Downloads/file.pfx:secret_key --cert-type P12 https://example.com/gettoken
```

When I run the above in curl I get a json object back with status ok and other data.

I tried to convert the same in perl

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
require LWP::Protocol::https;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(
SSL_ca_file   => '/Downloads/file.pfx',
);
my $test = $ua->post('https://example.com/gettoken');
```

When I do a dump on `$test` I get 500 error.  How do I pass in the cert type and secret key.  Or am I way off and this isn't the correct module.

Comment: Are you really sure that your Downloads directory is in your root directory?  If so, that's quite unusual.  Also, Perl is a language that encourages trying different approaches until one works.   Your error seems to indicate that the server can't handle your request appropriately (500), which might mean one of two things: the server is malfunctioing, or your request is just completely ridiculous.  The only upside is that your program is functioning, just not in a "server compatible" way.

Comment: Downloads was just an example.  I am looking for help with converting the curl command to perl.  I think the request is written correctly however I am not sure where to add the secret key and cert type the curl command is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new (
ssl_opts => {
  SSL_cert_file => '/path/to/file',
  #SSL_key_file  => $keyfile 
  SSL_passwd_cb => sub {"mysecretkey"},
}
);
my $res = $ua->get ("https://example.com/gettoken");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -i --cert /Downloads/file.pfx:secret_key ...
```

`--cert` is for a client certificate

```
...
SSL_ca_file   => '/Downloads/file.pfx',
```

SSL_ca_file is instead for the trust store. I.e. you use the same file for completely different tasks. For using as client certificate you have instead to use the `SSL_cert_file` option:

```
...
SSL_cert_file   => '/Downloads/file.pfx',
```

With a recent version of IO::Socket::SSL it should be able to transparently handle the PFX file. I'm not sure if it will work with a password protected PFX file though, but you can try to set the password with [SSL_passwd_cb](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Socket-SSL/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod#SSL_passwd_cb):

```
SSL_passwd_cb => sub { "secret_key" },
```

If this does not work and with older versions of IO::Socket::SSL you would need to extract cert and key in PEM format from the PFX file.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.